# warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcpy’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] the program work but how i fix the compiler error

Tags: c

```
struct student * createStudent(char studentName[],int studentAge){
struct student * ptr;
ptr= (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
strcpy(ptr->name,studentName);
ptr->age=studentAge;
ptr->next=NULL;

return ptr;
```

}

Compilation result :
60663645638018396.c: In function ‘createStudent’:
60663645638018396.c:46:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcpy’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
strcpy(ptr->name,studentName);
^
60663645638018396.c:46:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’

the program is working but i dont understand what is the compile error.

Answer (score 7):

[`strcpy()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) is declared in the header `string.h`.

Add

```
#include <string.h>
```

to the beginning of your code.